# selenium code is working on local, but getting error in Jenkins as Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

My code is as below:

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", CyberDependentBusinessRiskPage.cdbrLink);
```

When executed on local, it is working fine, but in Jenkins getting error as:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//body/app-dashboard[1]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/optimize-app[1]/div[1]/app-new-risk-model[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[3]"}
```

I am expecting that same code should run in `Jenkins` as well as the configuration is same.